# adding CSS to Grails

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I am still relatively new to Grails.  I am trying to use Bootstrap for the CSS.  I have added the bootstrap files to the CSS folder.  I have added the plugin.  I have added links to the head of the `main.gsp` as links and the pathing looks correct.  But still no joy.  I do not want to have a `<style></style>` in my gsp's.  Any advice on how to get the gsp to call the proper CSS?

Comment: I assume you added <r:require modules="bootstrap"/> to your main.gsp as the plugin indicates you should do? Take a look at the examples/docs: https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yeah I added it right under the layoutResourses  <r:layoutResources />
  <r:require modules="bootstrap"/>

Comment: I keep getting a resource not found error

Comment: Fortunately, you have to put them before laying out the resources. declare the modules and then layout what ever you have asked for. ;) Swap 'em.

Comment: That cleared my error but now the content on my index is gone just the head remains.

Comment: You have to once again `<r:layoutResources />` before the `</body>` ends.

Comment: They are in the head of the main.gsp

Comment: @tomsimo You need layoutResources in both head and body! :)

Comment: Thanks!!!! that did it.  In future, if I wanted to do some custom CSS just create a new resource and then add it the same way?